# Ensuring that vertical space is consistent in list of polynomials

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\[3x^3\]
\[3x^2\]
\[3x\]
\[3\]
\end{document}
```

When I render this document, there is a lot more space between the first two options than between the second and third options.  Is there a way to make sure it's consistent?  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, you might want `\usepackage{mathtools}` instead of `amsmath`. It fixes a couple of bugs and adds a feature or two. To read about mathtools, run `texdoc mathtools` in a terminal (assuming you have it installed, of course)

Comment: @kahen: shouldn't one use both? (Though I guess mathtools automatically includes amsmath?)

Comment: @Caramdir: Yes, it's automatically included. From the `mathtools` documentation: a line like `\usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{mathtools}` is equivalent to `\usepackage[fleqn,tbtags]{amsmath}\usepackage{mathtools}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `gather*` to put several equations after each other.

```
\begin{gather*}
3x^3\\
3x^2\\
3x\\
3
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: Awesome! That works perfectly. Thanks for helping this TeX noob!